# C# hashtable ContainsKey returning false when I know it have an entry with the key

Tags: c#, hashtable

```
 foreach (Ant ant in state.MyAnts)
        {
            if (m_foodTasks.ContainsKey(ant))
            {
...
```

By debugging I can see that there's an ant inside m_foodTasks with the exactly same values. So I will assume it compares the reference address..(am I right?)

How do I make it compare by value?

Edit after reading answers:

Too many info...
I will take a while to study those, but here is what the class ant already have ( I cant say what all those stuff is):

```
public class Location : IEquatable<Location> {

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the row of this location.
    /// </summary>
    public int Row { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the column of this location.
    /// </summary>
    public int Col { get; private set; }

    public Location (int row, int col) {
        this.Row = row;
        this.Col = col;
    }

    public override bool Equals (object obj) {
        if (ReferenceEquals (null, obj))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals (this, obj))
            return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof (Location))
            return false;

        return Equals ((Location) obj);
    }

    public bool Equals (Location other) {
        if (ReferenceEquals (null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals (this, other))
            return true;

        return other.Row == this.Row && other.Col == this.Col;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked {
            return (this.Row * 397) ^ this.Col;
        }
    }
}

public class TeamLocation : Location, IEquatable<TeamLocation> {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the team of this ant.
    /// </summary>
    public int Team { get; private set; }

    public TeamLocation (int row, int col, int team) : base (row, col) {
        this.Team = team;
    }

    public bool Equals(TeamLocation other) {
        return base.Equals (other) && other.Team == Team;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked {
            int result = this.Col;
            result = (result * 397) ^ this.Row;
            result = (result * 397) ^ this.Team;
            return result;
        }
    }
}

public class Ant : TeamLocation, IEquatable<Ant> {
    public Ant (int row, int col, int team) : base (row, col, team) {
    }

    public bool Equals (Ant other) {
        return base.Equals (other);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The GetHashCode() method needs to be overridden when checking for equality.

```
public class Ant : IEquatable<Ant>
{
    private string _someField;

    public Ant(string someField)
    {
        this._someField = someField;
    }

    #region Equality members

    public bool Equals(Ant other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return string.Equals(_someField, other._someField);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals((Ant) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (_someField != null ? _someField.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You can optionally create a IEqualityComparer class that does the comparing for you.

```
 private sealed class SomeFieldEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Ant>
    {
        public bool Equals(Ant x, Ant y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (x.GetType() != y.GetType())
            {
                return false;
            }
            return string.Equals(x._someField, y._someField);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Ant obj)
        {
            return (obj._someField != null ? obj._someField.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The class Ant is not mine, but I can see it already have overriden some Equals and GetHashCode methods, they deriving from IEquatable as well, I dont get any of this stuff..Theres no way to simple make it compare the damn key value? sounds simple doesnt it?

Comment: @Icebone1000 Have you checked to ensure that `GetHashCode` returns the same value for the two items that you belive are "equal".  If they don't, then they are not equal in the eyes of the dictionary.  The reason that you jump through these hoops with GetHashCode is specifically so that you *don't* need to compare the value you're searching for with all of the key values.  You only need to compare it with values that have the same hash code (which should be a tiny fraction) which makes it *much* more efficient.  If you want simplicity over efficiency use a different data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement GetHash and Equals correctly to make class behave as "compare values" in searches/dictionaries instead of "compare reference".

Another (potentially better option) is to provide [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) when creating dictionary.

Sample can be found in the article, here is compressed version:

```
Dictionary<Box, String> boxes = 
   new Dictionary<Box, string>(new BoxEqualityComparer());

class BoxEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Box>
{
  public bool Equals(Box b1, Box b2)
  {
    return b1.Height == b2.Height;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(Box bx)
  {
    return bx.Height.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```